# mysql ubuntu noinstall

Tags: mysql

I am looking for MySQL "no-install" version for Ubuntu.
I can successfully run MySQL on Windows (using MSI Installer as well as no-install).
With Ubuntu, MySQL got installed using the software center.

**My question is** --
Where do I find MySQL no-install version for Ubuntu.
Googled for it, but could not find the same.

Regards,

Vineet

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just do a `apt-get install mysql-server` and be done with it.

Comment: I wish to keep the entire mysql server & data on USB stick.   Just plug & play on any machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :    XAMPP

It is a package to run MySQL, Apache etc. without installing anything.

Answering my own question so that it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

The official Oracle MySQL binaries are here in archive format:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

At the bottom you will see:
Linux - Generic 2.6 (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive

Extract, the installation instructions are in the 'INSTALL' text file.